# Experimental Data Overlay/Fit

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, image, physics, signal-processing

I have two different sets of data represented in Contourplots:

[image: Data 1]

[image: Data2]

As you can see, in different positions of space, both have these very characteristic sets of four peaks (2 blue and 2 yellow). What I want to know if there is a function or method in Mathematica to spot those similarities and overlay them spacially by shifting the x and y coordinates, similar to what ImageAlign[] does to images I think.

Edit: I created two fileshare links including a .txt file with the data corresponding to each plot. The .txt files have three columns, x,y and f(x,y):

http://www.filedropper.com/data1_3 ; 
http://www.filedropper.com/data2_2

Answer (score 1):

I can't try without the actual data, but my first attempt would be a 2nd derivative Gaussian filter:

```
GaussianFilter[data, filterSize, {1,1}]
```

where `filterSize` is roughly the size of the 2 peak/2 value structure you're looking for.

This essentially convolves the data with a filter kernel that looks like this:

[image]

i.e. a Gaussian derived by x and y.

Comment: I edited my post and uploaded the data, in case you are available to try this out yourself. I will definitely try out your suggestion with GaussianFilter[] though, thank you very much